# UINavigationController switch views - slide from right to left

Tags: iphone, animation, uinavigationcontroller, transition

I am trying to switch between views.
The classes inherits from UINavigationController.
I am using this code in my IBAction:

```
    CellSubview *personView = [[CellSubview alloc] init]; // The new navigation controller
 self.modalTransitionStyle = 0; // tried all 3 of the options
 [self presentModalViewController:personView animated:YES];
 [personView release];
```

when :

```
     @interface CellSubview : UINavigationController
```

I just cant make the view to slide to the right. (as most of the applications does)

It always comes from the **bottom up** and non of the option:

```
  personView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
  // or
  personView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
```

I just want oldViewController.view slide left and the new newViewController.view to get in from the right.

Appreciate your advise

Itay

Answer (score 1):

The modalTransitionStyle property has to be set on the view controller, that is presented modally, that is on personView in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `presentModalViewController:`.  Use

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:personView animated:YES];
```

If you want to hide the navigation bar on the new screen, then use

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```